# How to get a value from JSP's drop down into a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a drop down list in a JSP which I am reading the values from and pass it into my servlet to perform actions based on the value received.
Below is my JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>

<body>
<form action="getdata.do" method="post">
<div align='left' >
    <div align='left' >
        <label class="text-white mb-3 lead">Which report do you want to generate?</label>
        <select id="reportSelection" data-style="bg-white rounded-pill px-5 py-3 shadow-sm " class="selectpicker w-100" name="reportselection">
            <option>Outage</option>
            <option>DataQuality</option>
            <option>Latency</option>
        </select>

        </head>
        <p id = "demo"> </p>
        <script>
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

<hr class="colorgraph">
<div class="row">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg register" tabindex="7"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I gave the drop down list an ID: `reportSelection`

In my servlet class, I tried to read it as below:

```
@WebServlet("/getdata.do")
public class DataServlet extends HttpServlet {

    String message;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In POST Method");
        getTableColumn gt = new getTableColumn();

        String issue      = request.getParameter("reportSelection");
        System.out.println("Drop Down Message: " + issue);

        try {
            System.out.println("In Try");
            if (issue.equals("Latency")) {
                message = gt.cruise("latency");
            } else if (issue.equals("DataQuality")) {
                message = gt.cruise("DataQuality");
                System.out.println("Data quality");
            } else if (issue.equals("Outage")) {
                message = gt.cruise("Outage");
            }
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            s.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I also printed the values of it just to see I am receiving any values from it.
But once I click on submit button, I see null pointer exception as

```
String issue      = request.getParameter("reportSelection");
```

is receiving NULL from JSP

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here & how do I correct it ?

Comment: watch the case, its case sensitive (ie the name) ;-)

Comment: Got it and corrected.